# how to display fields only when particular option in drop down is selected in django-admin

Tags: python, django

py looks as below,

```
     class Billing_Detail(models.Model):
        bill_choices = [('Permanent','Permanent'),('Temporary','Temporary')]
        emp_name = models.ForeignKey(Employee)
        bill_type = models.CharField(max_length = 10,choices=bill_choices,verbose_name='Bill type')
        start_date = models.DateField(blank=True,verbose_name='Billing Start Date',null=True)
        end_date = models.DateField(blank=True,verbose_name='Billing End Date',null=True)
```

Now in admin page I need to show start_date and end_date field only if the user choose bill_choice as Temporary. How can i do that. Do i need to write a java-script for it if so how can i register the java script with admin page in django

Answer (score 0):

This is the closest I got:

```
class BillingDetailAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    class Media:
        js = ('app/js/code.js', )  # Django will resolve the static URL on its own
```

Then in the page, I found jQuery to be bound to `grp.jQuery` or `django.jQuery` (unless you include your own jQuery there's the one that comes with Django admin), then I listen on dropdown changes then show/hide inputs accordingly.

Comment: is there any way in admin.py itself? so that instead of creating a custom template i use that

Comment: I don't think so, as you'll have to add your own custom Javascript somewhere. It doesn't have to be very intrusive you might get away with just overriding the one block where you can add your .js file

Comment: Hi I made an update, I just had to do this again, found a slightly better solution, maybe you have found better?